# How are ODBC connection credentials stored in MS Access?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, ado

I have an Access database that uses a login form to establish a connection to SQL Server using ADODB.Connection. The connection string contains the user credentials entered into the login form.

In a normal Access situation, if a pass through query is submitted with user credentials in the connection string, Access saves the credentials for use by other queries during the session, even if those queries don't include the credentials.

I would like to know how I can use the ADODB.Connection to login a user and then have Access automatically use the credentials when sending pass through queries going forward.

Comment: Uhhhh... Google? Bing? Yahoo? DogPile? Alta Vista?

Comment: If what you want is a connection that you open at startup and remains open and authenticated throughout the lifetime of your app, sure you can have that - run a macro at startup and open a global connection, then use it everywhere. That's terrible practice though. Objects, and especially database connections, should be as short-lived as possible. Do you know how to declare a `Const`, so that you don't need to actually type the whole connection string and credentials every time you need them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you used saved query for the PT query, then this works by default without any effort. And the same goes for linked tables.

So if all your PT queries and also ALL of your linked tables do NOT include the logon/password, then as you note ONCE you execute “anything” that has the logon/password, then now EVERY query, linked table, and PT query will automatic use that cached logon/password.

Thus to execute a PT query, you can now go at any time:

```
With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MyPass") 
  qdfPass.SQL = "exec sp_myProc" 
  qdfPass.Execute 
End With
```

Above is great, since you not messing with connection strings in code any more. and above is FAR less code then ADO examples.

So you HAVE to use the built in DAO objects to take advantage of the cached user/password. There is NOT a means to use ADO and ADO reocrdsets and then “grab” or “make use” of that cached logon/password that Access has as a connection string.

So using Access to automatic cache the logon/password is a GREAT way to avoid having to include the logon/user in any connection to the SQL server. And this approach means that NONE of your saved connecting strings has to include the logon/user.

This ALSO means you never have to mess with connection strings in near ALL of your code. A great way to centralize the "concept" of a connection in your application and NEVER have to include logon/user in such code after a one time logon.

However grabbing or obtaining that cached connection as a string in VBA that includes this information is not possible to my knowledge.

The result of above means you better off to use DAO and not ADO if possible, since then none of your actual code in the application has to supply or deal with connection strings.

You can cache the logon/user with this code:

```
Function TestLogin(strCon As String) As Boolean
  ' return true for a correct logon

  On Error GoTo TestError

  Dim dbs          As DAO.Database
  Dim qdf          As DAO.QueryDef

  Set dbs = CurrentDb()
  Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef("")

  qdf.Connect = strCon

  qdf.ReturnsRecords = False

'Any VALID SQL statement that runs on server will work below.

 qdf.SQL = "SELECT 1"
 qdf.Execute

 TestLogin = True

 Exit Function

   TestError:
      TestLogin = False
      Exit Function

End Function
```

I should also point that that ONCE you execute the above, there is NO POSSIBLE way to clear the password cache. This STRONGLY suggests that you have to exit the application to allow a different user to logon. You don’t necessary have to exit the application, but ANY connection string provided to the above routine with a INCORRECT logon/user will continue to return True and suggest you have a valid logon since if above fails, then Access will use a working cached logon/password for above and thus always return true – even for incorrect logon/user. (so passing a correct logon/user would cache and return true - a incorrect logon/user will STILL return true but use the previous cache user!!).

This quite much suggests that as a "genera" application design approach ***IF*** you are going to use this great cache feature of Access, then you limited to using the built in objects which are DAO based.